# Trouble Reading Lines of a File (Java)

Tags: java, file

So basically I need to take a file with output such as follows:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun z97 () Int
    2)
  (define-fun z88 () Int
    8)
```

and then define the values to the variables (I.e. set z97  = 2 and z88 = 8). Now I attempted to do this using a BufferedReader to read the file line by line. But looking at the documentation it does not appear there is a way to go to the next line in a BufferedReader while keeping track of the last line, so I have no idea how to go about parsing this. Do I need to use a different class? Any advice would be appreaciated.

Comment: Why can't _you_ keep track of the previous line? That's certainly out of the scope of a `Reader`s remit.

Comment: Like @boris said, you can do it yourself in e.g. a String object, an array, an ArrayList or something else.

Comment: I don't know why I did not think of that earlier, thanks guys!